# Something is wrong with the levels of my textures

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I'm trying to learn the UV mapping process in blender and I'm following a video tutorial. At a certain point,he says that there is the need to use adobe photoshop to paint the textures. I've been able to understand what to do until some point,but later I get stuck because I got a different result than that obtained by the author. I'm a totally newbie using photoshop,so I'm not able to explain well what I mean,so,I have attached two pictures. I hope that you can understand where is the error. In the first picture you see the result that I should reach and in the second one you can see my situation.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

As you can see,my uv maps aren't black and white,so something is wrong. thanks.

Comment: Could you share the tutorial you're following, or at least the steps in Photoshop you took to get where you are now?